# How 'vadd' + 1 works in case of iterating over String to print every char

Tags: assembly, addition, bytecode

i'am learning about assembly code. There is a snippet of program converted to byte code. Simply its printing out HelloWorld to the screen. Thing i do not understand is shifting to next char in loop. Why we add 1 to data from register (r4) to shift to the next char? How it`s done?

```
    data: db "Hello World", 0xa, 0
    vset r4, data
    vxor r0, r0
    vset r1, 1
    print_loop:
      vldb r2, r4
      vcmp r2, r0
      vjz .end
      voutb 0x20, r2
      vadd r4, r1
      vjmp print_loop
    .end:
```

Comment: Bytecode for what architecture or VM?  Also, having data mixed with code doesn't look right.  How does the CPU or interpreter know not to execute the `db` bytes as code?

Comment: But anyway, obviously `r4` is a pointer, like a C `char *p`, and adding 1 to it makes it point at the next character.  Also note the `ldb` load-byte instruction at the top of the loop using `r4`.  (I've never seen an ISA with these mnemonics, or a load instruction with 2 bare registers not an addressing mode.  But `ld` and `b` are very common parts of asm mnemonics, and from context it's obviously a byte load.  If that's not obvious to you, find a manual for whatever instruction-set this is so you can look up exactly what each instruction does.)

Comment: @PeterCordes i have specification for those instructions - its more excercise from the book than 'real' specification. I was just curious how adding '1'  points on the next character. I do not know much about C, i`m familiar with Java so that is counterintuitivefor me - you helped me anyway thanks.

Comment: The closest Java analogy for a pointer is an array iterator that you can add or subtract from, I think.  (Unsafe of course; in asm it's completely up to you whether / how you want to check bounds.  And this is a 0-terminated C-style implicit length string.)